# Duplicated Code in class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a problem I have a class which calls another class and its methods via objects. I'm creating and duplicationing the same code to create the object in every method. Is there a way to create the object in once place and have all the class methods use that same instance?

Comment: [Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc)

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement that common code in a method?

Comment: Could use a __construct for that or if I put it there would it not be recognized by the other methods.

Comment: @moonwave99 that not really going to help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method that creates a new Class instance like: 
If you dont need a new instance but want to use the same instance through runtime you can also save the created instance in a property.

```
class A
{
  protected function getB()
  {
    return new B();
  }


  public function method1()
  {
     $this->getB()->doSomething();
  }

  public function method2()
  { 
    $b = $this->getB();
    $b->doSomething();
  }
}


class B
{
  public function doSomething()
  {
    return 'something';
  }
}
```

Comment: You still end up creating the same object every time this way - you should look into Dependency Injection.